# Problems with network connection mac os x mountain lion

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, osx-mountain-lion

I'm having issues with my wireless network connection on my macbook pro 10.8.2
I thought it might be airport/hardware issues but it's not.

At the moment I'm using a wireless usb adapter (Realtek RTL8187B, pulled from my tv) and I'm
having connectivity issues with that as well.

The only message that shows up in console is

```
Jan 22 19:40:02 localhost configd[17]: network changed: v4(en2-:192.168.178.11) v6(en2-:fe80::2665:11ff:fea3:d11c) DNS- Proxy- SMB
Jan 22 19:40:08 localhost configd[17]: network changed: v4(en2+:192.168.178.11) DNS* Proxy+ SMB
Jan 22 19:40:11 localhost configd[17]: network changed: v4(en2!:192.168.178.11) v6(en2+:fe80::2665:11ff:fea3:d11c) DNS+ Proxy SMB
Jan 22 19:40:12 macbookpro-002241397ac5.fritz.box configd[17]: setting hostname to "macbookpro-002241397ac5.fritz.box"
```

And then the connection is disconnected. The only way to get the wireless connection back
is to turn wireless off and back on (this is for the usb wireless adapter) in the wireless network utility app provided by RealTek.

To get connectivity back for Airport only a reboot will work.

I'm really getting desperate here.
I can't even leave my mac to download stuff in peace, because I'm never sure it will finish
the download.

This is what I've tried so far.

I've used DTrace scripts provided with mac osx (mainly opensnoop) to try and find out what exactly configd is doing. I haven't gotten much wiser from it.

What I've found out is that whenever my wireless connection craps out the following files are accessed by configd.

```
2013 Jan 22 19:40:02     0     17 configd       -1 /etc/resolver
2013 Jan 22 19:40:02     0     17 configd        6 /etc/hostconfig
2013 Jan 22 19:40:02     0     17 configd        6 /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
2013 Jan 22 19:40:02     0     17 configd        6 /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
2013 Jan 22 19:40:06     0     17 configd        6 /dev/bpf0
2013 Jan 22 19:40:07     0     17 configd       22 /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
2013 Jan 22 19:40:07     0     17 configd       22 /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
2013 Jan 22 19:40:07     0     17 configd       22 /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server.plist
2013 Jan 22 19:40:07     0     17 configd       22 /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server.plist-lock
2013 Jan 22 19:40:07     0     17 configd       24 /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
2013 Jan 22 19:40:07     0     17 configd       24 /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
2013 Jan 22 19:40:07     0     17 configd       24 /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server.plist
2013 Jan 22 19:40:07     0     17 configd       24 /var/root/.CFUserTextEncoding
2013 Jan 22 19:40:08     0     17 configd       22 /dev/null
2013 Jan 22 19:40:08     0     17 configd       22 /etc/hostconfig
2013 Jan 22 19:40:08     0     17 configd        6 /dev/bpf0
2013 Jan 22 19:40:08     0     17 configd       -1 /etc/resolver
2013 Jan 22 19:40:08     0     17 configd       22 /etc/hosts
2013 Jan 22 19:40:08     0     17 configd       22 /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
2013 Jan 22 19:40:08     0     17 configd       22 /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
2013 Jan 22 19:40:10     0     17 configd       22 /dev/null
2013 Jan 22 19:40:11     0     17 configd       19 /var/run/resolv.conf-
2013 Jan 22 19:40:11     0     17 configd       -1 /etc/resolver
2013 Jan 22 19:40:11     0     17 configd       19 /etc/hostconfig
```

I also did a trace with execsnoop, to find out which processes where started by configd.
Not sure if it will be of help to anyone, but I'll include it anyways.

The following processes are started in all cases (ignore the timestamps, don't have a log from the 19:40 time point)

```
2013 Jan 22 03:15:00     0   7539      1 sh
2013 Jan 22 03:15:00     0   7541   7539 mktemp
2013 Jan 22 03:15:00     0   7540   7539 hostname
2013 Jan 22 03:15:01     0   7549   7546 date
2013 Jan 22 03:15:01     0   7550   7546 sh
2013 Jan 22 03:15:00     0   7548   7547 cat
2013 Jan 22 03:15:01     0   7553   7551 sed
2013 Jan 22 03:15:01     0   7556   7554 sed
2013 Jan 22 03:15:01     0   7562   7558 sed
2013 Jan 22 03:15:01     0   7559   7557 tee
2013 Jan 22 03:15:01     0   7563   7560 find
2013 Jan 22 03:15:01     0   7561   7557 wc
2013 Jan 22 03:15:01     0   7564   7560 find
2013 Jan 22 03:15:02     0   7565   7546 cat
2013 Jan 22 03:15:02     0   7566   7546 cp
2013 Jan 22 03:15:02     0   7567   7546 sh
2013 Jan 22 03:15:02     0   7568   7567 msgs
2013 Jan 22 03:15:02     0   7569   7546 cat
2013 Jan 22 03:15:02     0   7570   7546 cp
2013 Jan 22 03:15:02     0   7571   7546 sh
2013 Jan 22 03:15:02     0   7573   7572 find
2013 Jan 22 03:15:02     0   7574   7572 tee
2013 Jan 22 03:15:02     0   7575   7572 wc
2013 Jan 22 03:15:02     0   7576   7546 cat
2013 Jan 22 03:15:03     0   7577   7546 cp
2013 Jan 22 03:15:03     0   7578   7546 sh
2013 Jan 22 03:15:03     0   7579   7578 find
2013 Jan 22 03:15:03     0   7580   7546 cat
2013 Jan 22 03:15:03     0   7581   7546 cp
2013 Jan 22 03:15:03     0   7582   7546 sh
2013 Jan 22 03:15:03     0   7583   7546 cp
2013 Jan 22 03:15:03     0   7584   7546 sh
2013 Jan 22 03:15:03     0   7585   7584 df
2013 Jan 22 03:15:04     0   7586   7546 cat
2013 Jan 22 03:15:04     0   7587   7546 cp
2013 Jan 22 03:15:04     0   7588   7546 sh
2013 Jan 22 03:15:04   501   7589    696 mdworker
2013 Jan 22 03:15:04     0   7590   7588 netstat
```

Alex

Comment: Did you find out what is causing this problem? I'm getting similar message on iOS: `"configd[24] <Notice>: network changed: v4(pdp_ip0:X.X.X.X) DNS* Proxy""`